# Yii2, Event listener with javascript, on dropdown list populated with database

Tags: php, events, yii2

I have dropdown list with code like this

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'kodeBeras')->dropDownList(
        ArrayHelper::map(Beras::find()->all(), 'kodeBeras', 'namaBeras'),
        ['prompt'=>'Pilih Beras','style'=>'width:300px']
    ) 
?>
```

And below that there is a paragrpah which will be the result of event from above.
For example

```
'<h3>'var result'</h3>'
```

I want to insert Javascript event when dropdown value is change run 'function ambilData' on javascript.
`var result = (result from function)`.

I don't know where this `onchange` event should be placed within that dropdown.

or is there any other way to fix this problem ?

I have search on google and youtobe but I cannot get it.

for example ( event with php):
[Behavior and before request event](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f60ZZLgXAsg)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to use `onchange` event in dropdown list

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'kodeBeras')->dropDownList(
        ArrayHelper::map(Beras::find()->all(), 'kodeBeras', 'namaBeras'),
        [
           'prompt'=>'Pilih Beras','style'=>'width:300px',
           'onchange'=>'Your code here'
        ]
); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Via jQuery `change` event:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'kodeBeras')->dropDownList(
        ArrayHelper::map(Beras::find()->all(), 'kodeBeras', 'namaBeras'),
        [
            'prompt'=>'Pilih Beras',
            'style'=>'width:300px'
        ],
        ['id' => 'select']
    ) 
?>

<?php $this->registerJs("
    $('#select').on('change', function(){
        var val = $(this).val();
        console.log(val);
    });
");?>
```